# attempt to call a nil value (method '...') if __index not implemented in metatable

Tags: lua

Lua doesn't offer a unique way to OOP.

With `setmetatable` many alternatives are possible.

Here's what I tried:

```
Person={}

function Person.__call(cls,name)
    return setmetatable({name=name},cls)
end

function Person:say(what)
    print(self.name..'> '..what)
end

setmetatable(Person,Person)

p=Person('Fred')
p:say('hello') -- 18
```

which gives the error:

> 18: attempt to call a nil value (method 'say')

I can add:

```
function Person.__index(cls,k)
    return Person[k]
end
```

and then the above code works correctly, however I do not understand why the method is not found when `Person` is already metatable of itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the __index metavalue in order to relay indexing access operations. Having a metatable alone is not sufficient.

Also note that it is recommended to implement all meta methods befor using a table as a metatable.

Refer to the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 2.4 Metatables and Metamethods](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4)

> __index: The indexing access operation table[key]. This event happens when table is not a table or when key is not present in table. **The
> metavalue is looked up in the metatable of table**.
>
> The metavalue for this event can be either a function, a table, or any
> value with an __index metavalue. If it is a function, it is called
> with table and key as arguments, and the result of the call (adjusted
> to one value) is the result of the operation. Otherwise, the final
> result is the result of indexing this metavalue with key. This
> indexing is regular, not raw, and therefore can trigger another
> __index metavalue.

`__index` is that metavalue. So if you don't provide that metavalue, what should Lua do?

In the following example that metavalue is `Person`.
So when I call `a:sayName()`, Lua will find that `a.sayName` is nil. It will check if in `a`'s metatable `Person` there is a `__index` metavalue. There is and in this case it's a table named `Person` so it will index that person with key `"sayName"` which results in the following function call: `Person["sayName"](a)`

```
local Person= {}
Person.__index = Person

setmetatable(Person, {
  __call = function (cls, ...)
    return cls:_init(...)
  end,
})

function Person:_init(name)
  local o= setmetatable({}, self)
  o.name = name
  return o
end

function Person:sayName()
  print(self.name)
end

local a = Person("Lisa")

a:sayName()
```